# Infinite many solutions of $\varphi(2n+1)=\varphi(4n+1)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function, coprime

Related to this question :

[How far apart can be solutions of $\varphi(m)=\varphi(n)$ (while avoiding multiplicativities)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600525/how-far-apart-can-be-solutions-of-varphim-varphin-while-avoiding-multip)

> Does the equation $$\varphi(2n+1)=\varphi(4n+1)$$ have infinite many solutions ? $\ \varphi(n)\ $ is the totient-function.

The pari-code and the first solutions :

```
? for(n=1,10^7,if(eulerphi(2*n+1)==eulerphi(4*n+1),print1(n," ")))
656 926 3341 6386 14411 97061 99371 171746 351461 414896 654926 689981 923381 1000601 1394456 1955801 2699681 2732231 2844686 5364056 5658071 5888426 6041036 7294106 8293691 9805031 
?
```

A larger solution is $$10^{11}+5708611$$ If this equation has infinite many solutions, this implies that we can gave arbitary large differences between two coprime numbers with the same totient value.

Comment: The average ratio of reduction from $k$ to $\phi(k)$ for odd numbers is $\frac8{\pi^2}\approx0.81$ (with variance $\approx0.03$), so a reduction by a factor $2$ is quite rare and only occurs if $k$ is highly factorizable. So if this equation is satisfied, $2n+1$ will typically have few small prime factors and $4n+1$ will have many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather an experimental answer, may have been a comment, but there is no place for it there. The following table shows the first solutions, as in the long line in the OP, but here together with their factorizations. I was trying to find a (sub)pattern, but there is no pattern.

$$
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
n & 2n+1 & 4n+1 & \varphi(2n+1)=\varphi(4n+1)\\\hline\hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
656 & 13 \cdot 101 & 3 \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 7 & 2^{4} \cdot 3 \cdot 5^{2} \\
926 & 17 \cdot 109 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 19 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{3} \\
3341 & 41 \cdot 163 & 3^{5} \cdot 5 \cdot 11 & 2^{4} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5 \\
6386 & 53 \cdot 241 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 131 & 2^{6} \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \\
14411 & 19 \cdot 37 \cdot 41 & 3^{3} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 61 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5 \\
97061 & 17 \cdot 19 \cdot 601 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 181 & 2^{8} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5^{2} \\
99371 & 23 \cdot 8641 & 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 11^{2} \cdot 73 & 2^{7} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \\
171746 & 53 \cdot 6481 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 13^{2} \cdot 271 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \\
351461 & 13 \cdot 139 \cdot 389 & 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 4463 & 2^{5} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 23 \cdot 97 \\
414896 & 281 \cdot 2953 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 31 \cdot 43 \cdot 83 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 41 \\
654926 & 61 \cdot 109 \cdot 197 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \cdot 15877 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5 \cdot 7^{2} \\
689981 & 13 \cdot 101 \cdot 1051 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 751 & 2^{5} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{4} \cdot 7 \\
923381 & 31 \cdot 41 \cdot 1453 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 11^{3} \cdot 37 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 11^{2} \\
1000601 & 29 \cdot 151 \cdot 457 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \cdot 127 \cdot 191 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 19 \\
1394456 & 53 \cdot 101 \cdot 521 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 11 \cdot 6761 & 2^{7} \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 13^{2} \\
1955801 & 37 \cdot 71 \cdot 1489 & 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 43 \cdot 311 & 2^{7} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 31 \\
2699681 & 19 \cdot 31 \cdot 89 \cdot 103 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 67 \cdot 307 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \cdot 17 \\
2732231 & 17 \cdot 31 \cdot 10369 & 3^{5} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 257 & 2^{12} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5 \\
2844686 & 17 \cdot 43^{2} \cdot 181 & 3^{3} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 12041 & 2^{7} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 43 \\
5364056 & 11 \cdot 37 \cdot 43 \cdot 613 & 3^{3} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 19 \cdot 239 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 17 \\
5658071 & 47 \cdot 240769 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 277 \cdot 419 & 2^{8} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 11 \cdot 19 \cdot 23 \\
5888426 & 11 \cdot 223 \cdot 4801 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 101 \cdot 2221 & 2^{8} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 37 \\
6041036 & 113 \cdot 106921 & 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 23 \cdot 37 \cdot 631 & 2^{7} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \\
7294106 & 1013 \cdot 14401 & 3^{2} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 31 \cdot 47 \cdot 89 & 2^{8} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 11 \cdot 23 \\
8293691 & 113 \cdot 181 \cdot 811 & 3^{4} \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 6301 & 2^{7} \cdot 3^{6} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7 \\
9805031 & 11 \cdot 73 \cdot 24421 & 3 \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 7 \cdot 67 \cdot 223 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 11 \cdot 37 \\
10147121 & 17 \cdot 31 \cdot 97 \cdot 397 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 61 \cdot 6337 & 2^{12} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \\
10735481 & 47 \cdot 61 \cdot 7489 & 3^{2} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 13 \cdot 53 \cdot 277 & 2^{9} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 23 \\
12694481 & 41 \cdot 43 \cdot 14401 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 11 \cdot 61 \cdot 1009 & 2^{10} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 7 \\
14216951 & 127 \cdot 241 \cdot 929 & 3^{3} \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 71 \cdot 349 & 2^{10} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 29 \\
15824696 & 17 \cdot 37 \cdot 67 \cdot 751 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \cdot 19 \cdot 61 \cdot 331 & 2^{8} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 11 \\
15941981 & 29 \cdot 271 \cdot 4057 & 3^{3} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 13^{3} \cdot 43 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 13^{2} \\
16322696 & 11 \cdot 883 \cdot 3361 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 211 \cdot 421 & 2^{7} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7^{3} \\
16811876 & 47 \cdot 673 \cdot 1063 & 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 139 \cdot 827 & 2^{7} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 7 \cdot 23 \cdot 59 \\
19116746 & 17 \cdot 43 \cdot 193 \cdot 271 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 337 \cdot 2161 & 2^{12} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \\
19385756 & 11 \cdot 337 \cdot 10459 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 127 \cdot 1163 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5 \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 83 \\
20597750 & 1201 \cdot 34301 & 3 \cdot 7^{3} \cdot 11 \cdot 29 \cdot 251 & 2^{6} \cdot 3 \cdot 5^{4} \cdot 7^{3} \\
22752581 & 11 \cdot 4136833 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 229 \cdot 757 & 2^{8} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 19 \\
24149531 & 73 \cdot 751 \cdot 881 & 3^{2} \cdot 5^{4} \cdot 13 \cdot 1321 & 2^{8} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5^{4} \cdot 11 \\
24783536 & 41 \cdot 73 \cdot 16561 & 3^{3} \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \cdot 241 \cdot 277 & 2^{10} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 23 \\
24847046 & 73 \cdot 181 \cdot 3761 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 283 \cdot 1801 & 2^{9} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 47 \\
26960261 & 61 \cdot 263 \cdot 3361 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 211 \cdot 2621 & 2^{8} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 131 \\
28430651 & 97 \cdot 631 \cdot 929 & 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 61 \cdot 2437 & 2^{11} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 29 \\
28607213 & 71 \cdot 109 \cdot 7393 & 3^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 11^{2} \cdot 17 \cdot 883 & 2^{8} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5 \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 11 \\
34613636 & 1153 \cdot 60041 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 229 \cdot 2371 & 2^{10} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 19 \cdot 79 \\
39285386 & 29 \cdot 277 \cdot 9781 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \cdot 127 \cdot 7499 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 23 \cdot 163 \\
42671711 & 11 \cdot 37 \cdot 277 \cdot 757 & 3^{5} \cdot 5 \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 47 \cdot 61 & 2^{7} \cdot 3^{6} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 23 \\
43473581 & 17 \cdot 79 \cdot 101 \cdot 641 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 11 \cdot 41 \cdot 53 \cdot 97 & 2^{14} \cdot 3 \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 13 \\
48053381 & 17 \cdot 43 \cdot 73 \cdot 1801 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 193 \cdot 271 & 2^{11} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7 \\
48592451 & 17 \cdot 37 \cdot 367 \cdot 421 & 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 337 \cdot 1831 & 2^{9} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 61 \\
48634913 & 43 \cdot 641 \cdot 3529 & 3^{2} \cdot 7^{3} \cdot 11 \cdot 17 \cdot 337 & 2^{11} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5 \cdot 7^{3} \\
50343566 & 541 \cdot 186113 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 181 \cdot 4363 & 2^{10} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5 \cdot 727 \\
51642401 & 47 \cdot 109 \cdot 20161 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \cdot 1251937 & 2^{9} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 23 \\
54549731 & 11 \cdot 19 \cdot 151 \cdot 3457 & 3^{2} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 31 \cdot 41 \cdot 109 & 2^{10} \cdot 3^{6} \cdot 5^{3} \\
59908931 & 11 \cdot 421 \cdot 25873 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 197 \cdot 331 & 2^{7} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7^{3} \cdot 11 \\
60705206 & 17 \cdot 109 \cdot 65521 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 13 \cdot 37 \cdot 53 \cdot 127 & 2^{10} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 13 \\
63770231 & 29 \cdot 41 \cdot 67 \cdot 1601 & 3^{2} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 11 \cdot 23 \cdot 4481 & 2^{12} \cdot 3 \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \\
65986181 & 31 \cdot 701 \cdot 6073 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 11 \cdot 463 \cdot 691 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 23 \\
76902881 & 29 \cdot 127 \cdot 41761 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 13 \cdot 37 \cdot 8527 & 2^{8} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5 \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 29 \\
78990980 & 137 \cdot 1153153 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13^{2} \cdot 17 \cdot 5237 & 2^{10} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \\
79459553 & 37 \cdot 401 \cdot 10711 & 3^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 19 \cdot 101 \cdot 239 & 2^{7} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 7 \cdot 17 \\
88956176 & 353 \cdot 504001 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 151 \cdot 9241 & 2^{11} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \\
88983131 & 37 \cdot 1249 \cdot 3851 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 13 \cdot 79 \cdot 4621 & 2^{8} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \\
90323981 & 251 \cdot 719713 & 3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 19 \cdot 71 \cdot 3571 & 2^{6} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 17 \\
92523086 & 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 837313 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 29 \cdot 97 \cdot 179 & 2^{12} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 89 \\
96646016 & 11 \cdot 37 \cdot 71 \cdot 6689 & 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 29 \cdot 101 \cdot 419 & 2^{9} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 19 \\
98387606 & 37 \cdot 601 \cdot 8849 & 3^{2} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 17 \cdot 31 \cdot 3319 & 2^{9} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7 \cdot 79 \\
99314036 & 7 \cdot 193 \cdot 233 \cdot 631 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 43 \cdot 59 \cdot 73 & 2^{11} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 29 \\\hline
\end{array}
$$
Used [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) code:

```
for n in range( 10^8 ): 
    a, b = 2*n+1, 4*n+1 
    f, g = euler_phi(a), euler_phi(b) 
    if f == g: 
        print( r"%s & %s & %s & %s \\" 
               % (n, latex(factor(a)), latex(factor(b)), latex(factor(f))) )
```

(The output was designed to fit in an array environment.)

There is only one (vague) pattern, the fourth column contains only "small prime numbers". (The second column contains rather big factors, the third one has "smaller pieces".) So far i can see only coincidences, but no (sub) pattern, no (sub)scheme.

There may be a way to "force the luck" in an *experimental* search to deliver such coincidences. One such way is as follows. Let us fix a list of primes that we call "small", for instance the list $2,3,5,7,11,12,17,19,23$. We compute all primes $p$ up to $10^6$, so that $\varphi(p)=(p-1)$ has only such "small" factors in its decomposition. Up to $10^6$ there are $2217$ such primes. Consider all odd $a$ of the shape $a=p_1p_2p_3p_4$ (say). We build $b=2a-1$ and factor this number. By the "esoteric law of small factors", there is a (very small) percentage of obtained $b$ values, that are also having only factors from the $2217$ primes. We may expect then with a "higher probability" that $\varphi(a)$ has the same "magnitude" as $\varphi(b)$, so that the composition of the primes, and corresponding multiplicities, from $\varphi(a)$, $\varphi(b)$ may tend to the same. 
(There is a lot of heuristics in the above, in such cases i insert quotes to take distance from mathematics.)
The following code is "forcing the luck" in this manner (with $p_1,p_2,p_3\le 1000$).

```
solutions = []    # and we wil soon append

P0 = list(primes(24))    # P0 is the list 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23
S0 = set(P0)  
P1 = [ p for p in primes(3, 1000)
       if set( [ f for f, mul in (p-1).factor() ] ).issubset(S0) ]
P2 = [ p for p in primes(3, 1000000)
       if set( [ f for f, mul in (p-1).factor() ] ).issubset(S0) ]
for p1 in P1:
    for p2 in P1:
        if p2 <= p1: continue
        for p3 in P1:
            if p3 <= p2: continue
            for q1 in P2:
                if q1 <= p3: continue
                a = p1 * p2 * p3 * q1
                n = ZZ( (a-1)/2 )
                b = 4*n + 1
                f, g = euler_phi(a), euler_phi(b)
                if f == g:
                    solutions.append(n)
                    print("n=%s :: a = %s :: b = %s :: f = %s"
                          % (n, factor(a), factor(b), factor(f)))

solutions.sort()
for n in solutions:
    a, b = 2*n+1, 4*n+1 
    f = euler_phi(a)
    la = '%s' % latex(factor(a))
    lb = '%s' % latex(factor(b))
    lf = '%s' % latex(factor(f))
    print( "%s\n & %s\n & %s\n & %s\n\\\\" % (n, la, lb, lf) )
```

and the first *found* solutions are...

```
n=6364202666 :: a = 7 * 67 * 257 * 105601 :: b = 3 * 5 * 11^2 * 13 * 23 * 61 * 769 :: f = 2^17 * 3^3 * 5^2 * 11^2
n=54549731 :: a = 11 * 19 * 151 * 3457 :: b = 3^2 * 5^2 * 7 * 31 * 41 * 109 :: f = 2^10 * 3^6 * 5^3
n=5611760456 :: a = 11 * 19 * 641 * 83777 :: b = 3 * 5^2 * 13 * 17^2 * 29 * 41 * 67 :: f = 2^15 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 17
n=5364056 :: a = 11 * 37 * 43 * 613 :: b = 3^3 * 5^2 * 7 * 19 * 239 :: f = 2^6 * 3^5 * 5 * 7 * 17
n=96646016 :: a = 11 * 37 * 71 * 6689 :: b = 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 29 * 101 * 419 :: f = 2^9 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 19
n=42671711 :: a = 11 * 37 * 277 * 757 :: b = 3^5 * 5 * 7^2 * 47 * 61 :: f = 2^7 * 3^6 * 5 * 7 * 23
n=3541898981 :: a = 11 * 37 * 613 * 28393 :: b = 3^3 * 5^2 * 7 * 43 * 103 * 677 :: f = 2^8 * 3^5 * 5 * 7 * 13^2 * 17
n=256517651 :: a = 11 * 37 * 673 * 1873 :: b = 3^3 * 5 * 7 * 29 * 37441 :: f = 2^12 * 3^5 * 5 * 7 * 13
n=125801681 :: a = 11 * 43 * 211 * 2521 :: b = 3 * 5^2 * 7^3 * 31 * 631 :: f = 2^6 * 3^4 * 5^3 * 7^3
n=54977704556 :: a = 11 * 73 * 211 * 648961 :: b = 3 * 5^2 * 7 * 43 * 1951 * 4993 :: f = 2^13 * 3^4 * 5^3 * 7 * 13^2
n=1313592131 :: a = 11 * 79 * 337 * 8971 :: b = 3^2 * 5^2 * 7 * 47 * 70981 :: f = 2^7 * 3^3 * 5^2 * 7 * 13^2 * 23
n=9700960736 :: a = 11 * 97 * 883 * 20593 :: b = 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 67 * 521 * 3529 :: f = 2^11 * 3^5 * 5 * 7^2 * 11 * 13
n=9626428256 :: a = 11 * 181 * 577 * 16759 :: b = 3 * 5^2 * 13 * 19^2 * 31 * 3529 :: f = 2^10 * 3^6 * 5^2 * 7^2 * 19
n=5722645376 :: a = 13 * 41 * 241 * 89101 :: b = 3^3 * 5 * 11 * 31 * 37 * 89 * 151 :: f = 2^11 * 3^6 * 5^4 * 11
n=772881986 :: a = 13 * 61 * 401 * 4861 :: b = 3^3 * 5 * 11 * 17 * 151 * 811 :: f = 2^10 * 3^7 * 5^4
n=13772028926 :: a = 13 * 73 * 617 * 47041 :: b = 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 353 * 491 * 1009 :: f = 2^14 * 3^4 * 5 * 7^3 * 11
n=247793201 :: a = 13 * 137 * 463 * 601 :: b = 3 * 5 * 7 * 661 * 14281 :: f = 2^9 * 3^3 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 17
n=9409464083 :: a = 13 * 811 * 953 * 1873 :: b = 3^4 * 7^2 * 11 * 17^2 * 19 * 157 :: f = 2^10 * 3^7 * 5 * 7 * 13 * 17
n=10147121 :: a = 17 * 31 * 97 * 397 :: b = 3 * 5 * 7 * 61 * 6337 :: f = 2^12 * 3^4 * 5 * 11
n=124635236 :: a = 17 * 31 * 331 * 1429 :: b = 3 * 5 * 7^2 * 137 * 4951 :: f = 2^8 * 3^3 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 17
n=468154916 :: a = 17 * 31 * 757 * 2347 :: b = 3 * 5 * 7 * 181 * 98533 :: f = 2^8 * 3^5 * 5 * 7 * 17 * 23
n=1177122746 :: a = 17 * 31 * 919 * 4861 :: b = 3^3 * 5 * 11 * 19 * 109 * 1531 :: f = 2^8 * 3^9 * 5^2 * 17
n=15824696 :: a = 17 * 37 * 67 * 751 :: b = 3 * 5 * 11 * 19 * 61 * 331 :: f = 2^8 * 3^4 * 5^3 * 11
n=13033105496 :: a = 17 * 37 * 577 * 71821 :: b = 3 * 5 * 7 * 6841 * 72577 :: f = 2^14 * 3^7 * 5 * 7 * 19
n=48053381 :: a = 17 * 43 * 73 * 1801 :: b = 3 * 5^2 * 7^2 * 193 * 271 :: f = 2^11 * 3^5 * 5^2 * 7
n=19116746 :: a = 17 * 43 * 193 * 271 :: b = 3 * 5 * 7 * 337 * 2161 :: f = 2^12 * 3^5 * 5 * 7
n=43473581 :: a = 17 * 79 * 101 * 641 :: b = 3 * 5^2 * 11 * 41 * 53 * 97 :: f = 2^14 * 3 * 5^3 * 13
n=50275917461 :: a = 17 * 79 * 421 * 177841 :: b = 3^2 * 5 * 13 * 29 * 53 * 191 * 1171 :: f = 2^11 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 7 * 13^2 * 19
n=699394781 :: a = 17 * 79 * 991 * 1051 :: b = 3^2 * 5^3 * 11 * 23 * 9829 :: f = 2^7 * 3^4 * 5^3 * 7 * 11 * 13
n=674901521 :: a = 17 * 151 * 421 * 1249 :: b = 3 * 5 * 11 * 29 * 241 * 2341 :: f = 2^12 * 3^3 * 5^3 * 7 * 13
n=2924286499631 :: a = 17 * 769 * 991 * 451441 :: b = 3^3 * 5^2 * 13 * 31 * 89 * 397 * 1217 :: f = 2^17 * 3^6 * 5^2 * 11^2 * 19
n=2699681 :: a = 19 * 31 * 89 * 103 :: b = 3 * 5^2 * 7 * 67 * 307 :: f = 2^6 * 3^4 * 5 * 11 * 17
n=117635621 :: a = 19 * 41 * 79 * 3823 :: b = 3 * 5 * 7 * 491 * 9127 :: f = 2^6 * 3^4 * 5 * 7^2 * 13^2
n=101978291 :: a = 19 * 89 * 103 * 1171 :: b = 3^5 * 5 * 11 * 23 * 1327 :: f = 2^6 * 3^5 * 5 * 11 * 13 * 17
n=49909868258 :: a = 19 * 181 * 443 * 65521 :: b = 3 * 7 * 11 * 13^2 * 103 * 131 * 379 :: f = 2^8 * 3^6 * 5^2 * 7 * 13^2 * 17
n=223076863391 :: a = 23 * 257 * 953 * 79201 :: b = 3 * 5 * 11^2 * 67 * 281 * 26113 :: f = 2^17 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 7 * 11^2 * 17
n=63770231 :: a = 29 * 41 * 67 * 1601 :: b = 3^2 * 5^2 * 11 * 23 * 4481 :: f = 2^12 * 3 * 5^3 * 7 * 11
n=111706749041 :: a = 29 * 97 * 241 * 329551 :: b = 3 * 5 * 11 * 101 * 113 * 237277 :: f = 2^12 * 3^3 * 5^3 * 7 * 13^3
n=74217853091 :: a = 29 * 103 * 409 * 121501 :: b = 3^5 * 5 * 11 * 61 * 364141 :: f = 2^8 * 3^7 * 5^3 * 7 * 17^2
n=892826030 :: a = 29 * 109 * 181 * 3121 :: b = 3^3 * 7 * 11 * 17 * 37 * 2731 :: f = 2^10 * 3^6 * 5^2 * 7 * 13
n=18226725866 :: a = 29 * 109 * 953 * 12101 :: b = 3 * 5 * 11 * 73 * 1667 * 3631 :: f = 2^9 * 3^3 * 5^2 * 7^2 * 11^2 * 17
n=266773928231 :: a = 29 * 151 * 541 * 225217 :: b = 3^2 * 5^2 * 11 * 139 * 181 * 17137 :: f = 2^11 * 3^6 * 5^3 * 7 * 17 * 23
n=152691906161 :: a = 29 * 163 * 181 * 356929 :: b = 3^5 * 5 * 19 * 23 * 79 * 14561 :: f = 2^11 * 3^7 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13^2
n=2826696221 :: a = 29 * 277 * 601 * 1171 :: b = 3 * 5 * 11 * 131 * 631 * 829 :: f = 2^8 * 3^4 * 5^3 * 7 * 13 * 23
n=1467598481 :: a = 31 * 61 * 449 * 3457 :: b = 3 * 5^2 * 11 * 97 * 109 * 673 :: f = 2^16 * 3^5 * 5^2 * 7
n=3360501416 :: a = 31 * 97 * 601 * 3719 :: b = 3^2 * 5 * 11 * 101 * 313 * 859 :: f = 2^10 * 3^3 * 5^3 * 11 * 13^2
n=27408848756 :: a = 31 * 157 * 419 * 26881 :: b = 3 * 5^2 * 13 * 41 * 937 * 2927 :: f = 2^12 * 3^3 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19
n=9427565666 :: a = 31 * 193 * 331 * 9521 :: b = 3^3 * 5 * 17 * 29 * 103 * 5501 :: f = 2^12 * 3^3 * 5^3 * 7 * 11 * 17
n=4207534256 :: a = 31 * 353 * 379 * 2029 :: b = 3^2 * 5^2 * 13 * 67 * 157 * 547 :: f = 2^9 * 3^5 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13^2
n=1141470701 :: a = 37 * 89 * 761 * 911 :: b = 3 * 5 * 11 * 211 * 313 * 419 :: f = 2^9 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 19
n=427365188 :: a = 37 * 101 * 331 * 691 :: b = 3 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 569251 :: f = 2^6 * 3^4 * 5^4 * 11 * 23
n=34814713196 :: a = 37 * 109 * 281 * 61441 :: b = 3^2 * 5 * 13 * 41 * 5806081 :: f = 2^19 * 3^6 * 5^2 * 7
n=371007255791 :: a = 37 * 211 * 449 * 211681 :: b = 3^4 * 5 * 13 * 101 * 113 * 24697 :: f = 2^14 * 3^6 * 5^2 * 7^4
n=204192384866 :: a = 37 * 241 * 449 * 102001 :: b = 3 * 5 * 11 * 421 * 2161 * 5441 :: f = 2^16 * 3^4 * 5^4 * 7 * 17
n=194381227511 :: a = 37 * 673 * 883 * 17681 :: b = 3 * 5 * 13 * 73 * 1327 * 41161 :: f = 2^12 * 3^5 * 5 * 7^3 * 13 * 17
n=52503391586 :: a = 41 * 79 * 307 * 105601 :: b = 3^3 * 5 * 11 * 131 * 577 * 1871 :: f = 2^12 * 3^4 * 5^3 * 11 * 13 * 17
n=5054904206 :: a = 41 * 97 * 101 * 25169 :: b = 3 * 5^2 * 17 * 23 * 241 * 2861 :: f = 2^14 * 3 * 5^3 * 11^2 * 13
n=2573720531 :: a = 41 * 101 * 307 * 4049 :: b = 3 * 5^3 * 11 * 137 * 18217 :: f = 2^10 * 3^2 * 5^3 * 11 * 17 * 23
n=35252639711 :: a = 43 * 53 * 337 * 91801 :: b = 3 * 5 * 13^2 * 37 * 421 * 3571 :: f = 2^10 * 3^5 * 5^2 * 7^2 * 13 * 17
```

There are some "big" numbers $n$ in the above list, like 
$$n=2924286499631\ ,$$
so that the corresponding $a$ and $b=2a-1$ share the same Euler indicator. Initially, i was not expecting such an "abundance" of solutions.

In a table, the biggest solutions among all $112$ found solutions are:
$$
\begin{array}{|r||l|l|l|}
\hline
n & a=2n+1 & b=4n+1=2a-1 & \varphi(a)=\varphi(b)\\\hline\hline
398200176260
 & 139 \cdot 193 \cdot 251 \cdot 118273
 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 23 \cdot 47 \cdot 257 \cdot 21001
 & 2^{17} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 23
\\
505546711991
 & 163 \cdot 193 \cdot 937 \cdot 34301
 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 19 \cdot 61 \cdot 337 \cdot 547 \cdot 631
 & 2^{12} \cdot 3^{7} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7^{3} \cdot 13
\\
537814986701
 & 271 \cdot 397 \cdot 769 \cdot 13001
 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 31 \cdot 61 \cdot 67 \cdot 131 \cdot 8641
 & 2^{14} \cdot 3^{6} \cdot 5^{4} \cdot 11 \cdot 13
\\
559649282546
 & 79 \cdot 379 \cdot 881 \cdot 42433
 & 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 13^{3} \cdot 1009 \cdot 22441
 & 2^{12} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13^{2} \cdot 17
\\
559986932909
 & 151 \cdot 197 \cdot 337 \cdot 111721
 & 3^{2} \cdot 7^{5} \cdot 11 \cdot 29 \cdot 61 \cdot 761
 & 2^{10} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 7^{5} \cdot 19
\\
1072368107021
 & 97 \cdot 251 \cdot 829 \cdot 106261
 & 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 15401 \cdot 476101
 & 2^{10} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5^{4} \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 23^{2}
\\
1086000206456
 & 409 \cdot 673 \cdot 761 \cdot 10369
 & 3^{4} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 29 \cdot 37 \cdot 137 \cdot 14593
 & 2^{18} \cdot 3^{6} \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 17 \cdot 19
\\
1751161800656
 & 137 \cdot 199 \cdot 601 \cdot 213751
 & 3^{3} \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 23 \cdot 31 \cdot 1021 \cdot 2851
 & 2^{8} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5^{6} \cdot 11 \cdot 17 \cdot 19
\\
2143261968761
 & 157 \cdot 197 \cdot 307 \cdot 451441
 & 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 19 \cdot 79 \cdot 103 \cdot 421 \cdot 2927
 & 2^{9} \cdot 3^{6} \cdot 5 \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19
\\
2924286499631
 & 17 \cdot 769 \cdot 991 \cdot 451441
 & 3^{3} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 13 \cdot 31 \cdot 89 \cdot 397 \cdot 1217
 & 2^{17} \cdot 3^{6} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 11^{2} \cdot 19
\\
2997732680885
 & 151 \cdot 617 \cdot 757 \cdot 85009
 & 3^{2} \cdot 7^{2} \cdot 11^{2} \cdot 23^{2} \cdot 421 \cdot 1009
 & 2^{10} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7^{3} \cdot 11^{2} \cdot 23
\\
3741666657971
 & 67 \cdot 193 \cdot 701 \cdot 825553
 & 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 19 \cdot 43 \cdot 127 \cdot 2081 \cdot 4621
 & 2^{13} \cdot 3^{6} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 7^{3} \cdot 11 \cdot 13
\\
5709893608901
 & 163 \cdot 281 \cdot 641 \cdot 388961
 & 3^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 131 \cdot 241 \cdot 331 \cdot 2857
 & 2^{16} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5^{3} \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17
\\
23303182569560
 & 229 \cdot 277 \cdot 881 \cdot 833977
 & 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 17 \cdot 19^{2} \cdot 37 \cdot 2179 \cdot 8971
 & 2^{11} \cdot 3^{8} \cdot 5 \cdot 11^{2} \cdot 13 \cdot 19 \cdot 23
\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

---

It is easy to rewrite the code so that it searches for solutions $a$ of the shape $a=p_1p_2\dots p_k$, where each prime is in a specified (smaller or bigger) range. To have solutions bigger $10^{15}$, say, we may try to force two "big" factors, $p_3,p_4$ with seven or eight digits. The "smaller" factors $p_1,p_2$ may support the luck. The bigger they can be, the greater the chances to find a solutions. But the running time also increases. Working with $p_1,p_2\le 100$, $10^6\le p_3,p_4\le 10^9$, may seem to be a fair choice. But under such circumstances, there is no "abundance" of solutions. In fact, after some hours of search i had no found solution and stopped the run. (This may be also an issue joined with the "thin air" of allowing in $\varphi(a)=\varphi(b)$ only prime factors $\le 23$.

---

This is all i have, i have no structural idea to force a "positive density" (in any sense) for the solutions $a$ of $\varphi(a)=\varphi(2a-1)$.

---

Later EDIT: It was really a singular experience to see so much realizations for $\varphi(a)=\varphi(2a-1)$, a product of "small primes", so that i tried to see if similar searches (with only four prime factors) also give solutions for some bigger $n$, say $n>10^{15}$. After some trial and error sage showed the following solution:

$$
\begin{aligned}
n &= 1\;660\;867\;932\;705\;770\ ,
\\
a &=2n+1 = 2311 \cdot 3457 \cdot 5501 \cdot 75583\ ,
\\
b &=4n+1= 3^{3} \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 53 \cdot 89 \cdot 127 \cdot 1871 \cdot 2851\ ,
\\
\varphi(a)&=\varphi(b)
= 2^{11} \cdot 3^{6} \cdot 5^{4} \cdot 7 \cdot 11^{2} \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I was very impressed by the number theoretical richness of the solutions, so i tried to find also "bigger" solutions, so that the many solutions found with the first found "small numbers" do not appear to be a feature that breaks after some level. Sage delivered the following rather high solution, $$n=1660867932705770\ .$$I edited the answer by appending this information, and also giving the factorizations for $2n+1$, $4n+1$, and the common value $\varphi(2n+1)=\varphi(4n+1)$.